# How can I make use of a method that is part of a restcontroller in java code?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

For e.g. when I try to invoke the following method which is part of PersonController

```
@RequestMapping("/selectnamelbyid")     
public Template selectNamesbyID(@RequestParam(value = "id") String id) {...
```

using the code below

```
PersonController personController = new PersonController();
personController.selectNamesbyID(id);
```

it throws a nullpointer. 
I am trying to centralize the data fetching logic to the controller class by doing this. Can someone tell what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to post more code and/or the exception for this to be answerable.

Comment: IoC - don't call me, I'll call you -- and nobody else can call you either :)

Comment: Keep your data fetching logic into service layer and use that service in multiple controllers.

Comment: @ravi that is a good idea. Should have thought about that before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe PersonController should be initialized by spring container. It can be injected into your code somewhere but it will not work if you new this instance manually.